# How can i format my callback so that the dash graph works properly?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Please advise on how I can change the callback so that it works and the graph displays correctly.

I think the for loop is incorrect?

The previous indentation issue is fixed.

Could you advise?

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

import plotly.graph_objs as go

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("crude-oil-production2.csv", sep=","  ,index_col=0)

countries = df['COUNTRYNAME'].unique()
Year = df['Year'].unique()

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Oil Data'),

    html.Div([
        html.Label('Country'),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='country',
            options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in countries],
            value='',
            placeholder='Select...',
            multi=False
        )
    ],    
    style={'width': '20%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'margin-bottom': '20px'}),    

    html.Div([
        html.Label('Year'),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='Year',
            options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in Year],
            value='',
            placeholder='Select...',
            multi=False
        )
    ],    
    style={'width': '20%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'margin-bottom': '20px'}),   

    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='Country vs Year'),
    ],
    style={'width': '70%'}),
]) 

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('Country vs Year', 'figure'),
    [
        dash.dependencies.Input('Year', 'value'),
        dash.dependencies.Input('country', 'value')
    ])
def update_graph(expectancy, country):
    filtered_df1 = df.loc[df["COUNTRYNAME"] == Country] 
    filtered_df = filtered_df1.loc[filtered_df1["Year"] == Year]

    traces = []
    for i in filtered_df:
        traces.append(go.Scatter(
            x=filtered_df['Months'],
            y=filtered_df['Thousand_Barrels_per_day__kb_d'],
            text=filtered_df['country'],
            mode='markers',
            opacity=0.7,
            marker={
                'size': 15,
                'line': {'width': 0.5, 'color': 'white'}
            },
            name=i
        ))

    return {
        'data': traces,
        'layout': go.Layout(
            xaxis={'title': 'Months', 'titlefont': dict(size=18, color='darkgrey'), 'zeroline': False, 'ticks': 'outside' },
            yaxis={'title': 'Thousand_Barrels_per_day__kb_d', 'titlefont': dict(size=18, color='darkgrey'), 'range': [30, 90], 'ticks': 'outside'},
            margin={'l': 60, 'b': 60, 't': 30, 'r': 20},
            legend={'x': 1, 'y': 1},
            hovermode='closest'
        )
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The graph to display, with interactivity working.

Comment: You're missing a ':' on the for loop, it should read "for i in filtered_df:"

Comment: I've put it in.

Comment: You need to show a full traceback. The error is self explanatory. You're mixing tabs and spaces in the indentation

Comment: Thanks.
I've put the full error in.

Comment: Can you include a dummy dataframe so that I can try to run this on my end?